# Execute commands in queue and async

Tags: node.js

NodeJS newbie (this is my first node app).
How can I execute commands (from the command line) in order? Like in a queue, one after another. Note that some commands could take several seconds.
I would like to do it without blocking node, in an asynchronous way.

Is this what I need:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/command-queue

I find strange having to call RUN every time I add a command. I mean, the queue should work always.

Thanks a lot for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The npm package you listed looks reasonable, and it has an `async` method where you can list the commands one after another:

```
new CommandQueue()
.async(
    'karma start',
    'webpack-dev-server --hot'
)
.run();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I will add commands when a switch is pressed (I would like to use with homebridge), so every time it is pressed, a new command is added in the queue (and commands could take seconds). But, what I don't understand is having to call RUN when I add a new command. Is that normal? Apart from that I guess I have to save the queue in a global variable. What do you think? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see what's strange having to call `run` every time you add a new command. Just make sure you're not calling previous commands over again unless they're necessary. Every time a switch is pressed, is there a variable command to run, like including an on or off flag? In that case you could modify the string(s) inside the `async` call appropriately.